# Bootstrap responsive form - label placement

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get the labels on this bootstrap form to position correctly both for mobile devices and desktop screens.

Fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/93182/

Note how its ok on a narrow screen:

[image]

But gets messed up on a wide screen:

[image]

Is this to do with float, or padding?

Sample html for one input is:

```
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="surname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Surname</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control person surname"
                               style="text-transform: uppercase" data-property="surname"
                               placeholder="SURNAME" th:field="*{person.surname}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**UPDATE**
I added lg to the first row but the issue with the labels is the same: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/93188/

**UPDATE 2**

leaving the labels to look like:

```
<label for="surname" class="control-label">Surname</label>
```

Didn't work either

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap comes with the different class for different screen width. 
Grid Classes

The Bootstrap grid system has four classes:

```
    xs (for phones - screens less than 768px wide)
    sm (for tablets - screens equal to or greater than 768px wide)
    md (for small laptops - screens equal to or greater than 992px wide)
    lg (for laptops and desktops - screens equal to or greater than 1200px wide)
```

The classes above can be combined to create more dynamic and flexible layouts.

Tip: Each class scales up, so if you wish to set the same widths for xs and sm, you only need to specify xs.

You need to add something like col-lg-4 to make it looks good on wider screen.

You can reference to this : https://www.w3schools.com/booTsTrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: so you can have class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2 control-label" ?

Comment: The xs and sm class are for phone and from md and up the classes are for tablet and desktop.

Comment: Yes, you can. It will be putting in different css section. And show up in different size.

Answer (score 0):

What version of bootstrap are you using? I see your css is version 3.0.0, but what about your js files? Here's what it looks like with version 4:

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/


/* Optional theme */

body {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Subject</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="panel-body">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">NID</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8 input-group nid">
            <input type="number" class="form-control inputnid person text-uppercase" data-property="nid" id="nid" placeholder="NID" th:field="*{person.nid}" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="surname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Surname</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control person surname" style="text-transform: uppercase" data-property="surname" placeholder="SURNAME" th:field="*{person.surname}" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="firstname" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Firstname(s)</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control  person" data-property="firstname" placeholder="Firstname" th:field="*{person.firstname}" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control  person" data-property="middlename" placeholder="Middlename" th:field="*{person.middlename}" />
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="streetAddress" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control address" id="address" data-property="formattedAddress" placeholder="Street Address" th:field="*{person.address}" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="gender" class="col-sm-5 control-label left">Gender</label>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <select class="selectpicker form-control  person" data-property="gender" title="Choose" data-width="100px" name="gender" th:field="*{person.gender}">
              <option value="Male">Male</option>
              <option value="Female">Female</option>
              <option value="Unknown">Unknown</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dob" class="col-sm-2 control-label">DOB</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="input-group date">
              <input type="text" class="form-control dob person" data-property="dob" name="dob" th:field="*{person.dob}" />
              <span class="input-group-addon">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="phonehome" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ph</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="tel" class="form-control  person" data-property="phoneHome" id="phonehome0" placeholder="Telephone No" th:field="*{person.phoneHome}" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">


      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="ethnicity0" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ethnicity</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="selectpicker form-control person ethnicity" data-property="ethnicity" name="ethnicity" id="ethnicity0" data-live-search="true" title="Choose" data-width="100%" th:field="*{person.ethnicity}">
              <option value="European">European</option>
              <option value="Maori">Maori</option>
              <option value="Indian">Indian</option>
              <option value="PI - Samoan">PI - Samoan</option>
              <option value="PI - Tongan">PI - Tongan</option>
              <option value="PI - Cook Island">PI - Cook Is</option>
              <option value="PI - Fijian">PI - Fijian</option>
              <option value="PI - Fijian Indian">PI - Fijian Indian</option>
              <option value="Niuean">PI - Niuean</option>
              <option value="PI - Other">PI - Other</option>
              <option value="Asian - Chinese">Asian - Chinese</option>
              <option value="Asian - Thailand">Asian - Thailand</option>
              <option value="Asian - Vietnamese">Asian - Vietnamese</option>
              <option value="Asian - Laos">Asian - Laos</option>
              <option value="Asian - Other">Asian - Other</option>
              <option value="Middle East - Iraq">Middle East - Iraq</option>
              <option value="Middle East - Iran">Middle East - Iran</option>
              <option value="Middle East Other">Middle East Other</option>
              <option value="African - South African">African - South African</option>
              <option value="African - Zimbawe">African - Zimbabwe</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-5"></div>

      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="phonemobile" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Pm</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="tel" class="form-control  person" data-property="phoneMobile" id="phonemobile" placeholder="Telephone No" th:field="*{person.phoneMobile}" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks nice in bootstrap4 but I have to use bootstrap3 for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place correctly the labels you don't need to assign them a class because they will automatically place on top of your text input.

Read the docs about http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/